# How to find an angle between the extension of a diameter and a chord in a semicircle

Tags: circles, angle

[image: The picture for the following question]

O is the center of the semicircle, if $\angle EOD = 45^\circ$ and OD = AB, find $\angle BAC$

I don't know what theorem I should use, I've tried to connect many dots to reach the answer but still can't find it. Can anyone show me a hint?

Comment: $OD=AB=BO=OE$ giving you two isosceles triangles when you draw $OB$

Comment: I've already tried that one, and I'm literally stuck at this part. Can you tell me what I should do next?

Comment: $\angle{OEB}=\angle{OBE}=2\angle{BAC}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\angle BAC=\alpha$

$\triangle ABO$ is isosceles with $\angle BAO=\angle AOB=\alpha$ and $\angle ABO=180-2\alpha$

$\angle OBE=180-\angle ABO=2\alpha$

$\triangle BOE$ is isosceles with $\angle OBE=\angle BEO=2\alpha$ and $\angle BOE=180-4\alpha$

Now you have $\angle AOB+\angle BOE+\angle EOD=180$

$\alpha+(180-4\alpha)+45=180$

$45-3\alpha=0$

$\alpha=15$